# The "Send to" menu does not appear on context menu when I right-click on a drive?

Tags: windows-7, send-to

I am using Windows 7. When I open my computer and right-click on the icon of one of the drives, the send to menu does not appear. I want to send a drive to programs in the send to menu. What is the solution?

Comment: I don't think the "Send To..." menu appears on a drive. Most of those features would be useless on a drive. the only one that seems almost right is "Send To > Desktop (create shortcut)". I know the menu does not appear on a drive in Win10.

Comment: @frank-thomas The "Send to..." menu is customizable and I can add my own options.  My question is how to enable it for drives?

Comment: For example, I want to send a drive to WinDirStat, which I have already created a shortcut in "SendTo", and it is important to have a context menu for the drive

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question,
This must be created in the Windows registry

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SendTo]
@="{7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}"
```

By Searching the Windows registry, I found that the "Send to" menu is defined here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SendTo
```

And this does not include the drive. So I have to find the `ContextMenuHandlers` for the drive and that's it

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SendTo
```

Now I set the default value of this path with:

```
{7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}
```

And now it works properly. Drives also have a "Send To" menu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).